# Add exclusion to Excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm using this macro to save individual excel worksheets as their own PDF when run:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sPath       As String
Dim wks         As Worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = .Path & "\"
    For Each wks In .Worksheets
            sFile = wks.Name & ".pdf"
            wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next wks
End With
End Sub
```

I would just like to add to it to not start from a certain worksheet or to exclude certain worksheets. Any clue how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select Case` to specify sheetnames to ignore, as shown.  Simply replace the "IgnoreSheet1", "IgnoreSheet2" with the actual sheet names you want skipped.  It's just a comma delimited list, so add as many as you want.

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sPath       As String
Dim wks         As Worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = .Path & "\"
    For Each wks In .Worksheets
        Select Case wks.Name
            Case "IgnoreSheet1", "IgnoreSheet2"     'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Code here to run on the other sheets
                sFile = wks.Name & ".pdf"
                wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                        Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End Select
    Next wks
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work. I might have placed it wrong. Can you share with the full macros?